# Loading screen images in Sniper Elite 3

Tags: sniper-elite-3

The loading screens in Sniper Elite 3 offer a variety of gameplay tips and hints, but most of the time they disappear before I can finish reading them.

Is there anywhere I can browse the images at my own leisure? I found a few online but they're mostly very low-res. Is there any way to extract them from the game files (I'm playing on PC)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find those [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NG1sGQ5aOOA), i hope the resolution is what you are looking for.